# How to view the mercurial diff between local and repository?

Tags: mercurial, diff

Hi
Using Mercurial I'm looking for a command to display for example files I didn't add.
Can you specify if there's a name for the command I'm looking for? Like displaying the difference between the repository and local.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`hg status` will show the state of all modified, added, removed or unknown files.  Use `hg status --unknown` to show files in your working directory that aren't in the repository.  It has several other command line switches as well: see `hg help status` for details.

Comment: Thank you Niall.  hg status -unknown . (I had to add the dot for the current directory) is good to know now.